how to look at the space of infinite binary grids
i'm looking for a way to map points in a finite-dimensional space (discrete or continuous, whatever's most natural) uniquely to maps $\mathbb{Z}^2\mapsto\{0,1\}$ (ie. to infinite 2d grids where each cell contains either a zero or a one - the motivation is to lay out the space of possible game-of-life states). is there a natural way(s) of doing this?

Why do you want to do this? You can just directly consider the infinite 2d grids. There's no issue with just writing down the full set of arbitrary maps $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to { 0, 1 }$.

@QiaochuYuan i'm curious about the patterns in how long (and whether) a life configuration reaches a loop, and to visualise them to get an intuition about any large-scale patterns it'd be nice to lay them out in some natural way

Wouldn't you want a map going in the opposite direction then? From 2d grids to points in some space? Also, do you want arbitrary grids or only grids with a finite number of $1$s?

well, the setup i have currently is for a more limited version where i'm plotting a graph of the lifetime of all the grids that start with an x by y square, but it'd be good to go in the other direction too. i don't immediately see any way to make use of infinitely nonrepeating grids, so i guess it doesn't matter whether we have those ones
